# Elegant Matrix Combinations

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, manipulate

Suppose you have a matrix (mxn), simplified for illustration

```
m= {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}
```

And a set of combinations (simplified for illustration purposes but can contain more combinations...)

```
combinations = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}}
```

What is the best way to derive a matrix that holds all the combinations of the matrix m? As an illustration:

```
m1 = {{a, b, c}, {a, b, -c}, {a, -b, c} … … …  {-d,-e,-f} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Here is a pretty fast way:

```
Transpose[
 Transpose[m] Transpose[ConstantArray[combinations, Length[m]], {2, 3, 1}],
 {3, 1, 2}]

(* {{{a, b, c}, {a, b, -c}, {a, -b, c}, {a, -b, -c},
     {-a, b, c}, {-a, b, -c}, {-a, -b, c}, {-a, -b, -c}},
    {{d, e, f}, {d, e, -f}, {d, -e, f}, {d, -e, -f},
     {-d, e, f}, {-d, e, -f}, {-d, -e, f}, {-d, -e, -f}} *)
```

Like my others, it needs to be flattened 1 level (`Flatten[%, 1]`) to get it in the exact form requested.

Comparison:

```
m = RandomReal[9, {150000, 3}];

Flatten[Transpose[
      Transpose[m] Transpose[ConstantArray[combinations, Length[m]], {2, 3, 1}],
      {3, 1, 2}], 1] // Timing // First]; (* Michael E2*)
Join @@ Tuples /@ Outer[Times, m, {1, -1}] // Timing // First (*Mr.Wizard*)
Times @@@ Tuples[{m, Tuples[{1, -1}, 3]}] // Timing // First (*belisarius*)

(* 0.107418
   0.671081
   1.934405 *)
```

---

**Original answer**

A few variations on @belisarius' way, in the sense that they're all about lining rows up for `Times`.  But since he's already used `Tuples`, these all need some flattening (or for variety, via `Sequence` in the last two).

```
Flatten[Outer[Times, m, combinations, 1], 1]

Flatten[(Function[x, x #] /@ combinations) & /@ m, 1]

Block[{fn}, fn[row__] := Sequence @@ (# {row} & /@ combinations);
  fn @@@ m ]

m /. x_?VectorQ :> Sequence @@ (x # & /@ combinations)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use to find all combinations for 1 & -1.

```
t = Tuples[{1, -1}, 3]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 
>     1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}}

than just find product,

```
{t.m[[1]], t.m[[2]]}
```

> {{a + b + c, a + b - c, a - b + c, 
>     a - b - c, -a + b + c, -a + b - c, -a - b + c, -a - b - c}, {d + e +
>       f, d + e - f, d - e + f, 
>     d - e - f, -d + e + f, -d + e - f, -d - e + f, -d - e - f}}

or Simply

```
Partition[Flatten[t.# & /@ m], 1]
```

> {{a + b + c}, {a + b - c}, {a - b + c}, {a - b - c}, {-a + b + 
>      c}, {-a + b - c}, {-a - b + c}, {-a - b - c}, {d + e + f}, {d + e -
>       f}, {d - e + f}, {d - e - f}, {-d + e + f}, {-d + e - f}, {-d - 
>      e + f}, {-d - e - f}}

Edit:Considering above output as t1.

```
 Flatten[Table[t1[[i]] /. Plus -> List, {i, Length[t1]}], 1]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, -c}, {a, -b, c}, {a, -b, -c}, {-a, b, c}, {-a, 
>     b, -c}, {-a, -b, c}, {-a, -b, -c}, {d, e, f}, {d, e, -f}, {d, -e, 
>     f}, {d, -e, -f}, {-d, e, f}, {-d, e, -f}, {-d, -e, f}, {-d, -e, -f}}

Comment: that doesn’t work… note that I am interested in a final matrix of the form: {{a,b,c},{a,b,-c}} not {{a+b+c},{a+b-c}} as you have it...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps easier:

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
combinations = Tuples[{1, -1}, 3];
Times @@@ Tuples[{m, combinations}]
```

> {a,b,c}
>   {a,b,-c}
>   {a,-b,c}
>   {a,-b,-c}
>   {-a,b,c}
>   {-a,b,-c}
>   {-a,-b,c}
>   {-a,-b,-c}
>   {d,e,f}
>   {d,e,-f}
>   {d,-e,f}
>   {d,-e,-f}
>   {-d,e,f}
>   {-d,e,-f}
>   {-d,-e,f}
>   {-d,-e,-f}

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is code that is faster than your presently Accepted solution:

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};

Tuples /@ Outer[Times, m, {1, -1}]
```

> {{{a, b, c}, {a, b, -c}, {a, -b, c}, {a, -b, -c}, {-a, b, c}, {-a, b,
>   -c}, {-a, -b, c}, {-a, -b, -c}},
>    {{d, e, f}, {d, e, -f}, {d, -e, f}, {d, -e, -f}, {-d, e, f}, {-d, e,
>   -f}, {-d, -e, f}, {-d, -e, -f}}}

You can use `Join @@` if you want all triplets in a single list.  Timings:

```
m = RandomReal[9, {150000, 3}];

Join @@ Tuples /@ Outer[Times, m, {1, -1}] // Timing // First (* Mr.Wizard *)
Times @@@ Tuples[{m, Tuples[{1, -1}, 3]}]  // Timing // First (* belisarius *)
```

> 0.437
>
> 1.014