# Signed power set of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, subset

Given `{a, b, c, ...}` with $n$ elements generate a list with $2^n$ elements.

For example, if the list were `{a, b, c}`, then the output should be

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, -c}, {a, -b, c}, ..., {-a, -b, -c}}
> ```

If possible, I want to use buit-in functions so that the task can be performed without looping. My own solutions using `Subsets[{-1,-1,...}` are very messy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait a few hour for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Comment: Related: [(30664)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30664/121), 
[(47285)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47285/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

```
f[list_] := list # & /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, Length[list]]
```

### Example

```
f[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, -d}, {a, b, -c, d}, {a, b, -c, -d}, {a, -b, c, d}, {a, -b, c, -d}, {a, -b, -c, d}, {a, -b, -c, -d}, {-a, b, c, d}, {-a, b, c, -d}, {-a, b, -c, d}, {-a, b, -c, -d}, {-a, -b, c, d}, {-a, -b, c, -d}, {-a, -b, -c, d}, {-a, -b, -c, -d}}
> ```

### Explanation

[`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) generates a list of all possible n-tuples of elements from list.

```
Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]
```

> ```
> {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Then the hieroglyphics part, `list # & /@`, multiplies the `list` to each sublist of the combinations of `1`s and `-1`s, using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`) and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) (`# &`)

Comment: I knew there was a simple way...thank you.

Comment: +1 for `Tuples` but there is a cleaner and faster formulation available; please see my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed better, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I too would use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tuples.html) but a bit differently.  I propose:

```
f2[a_List] := Tuples[ {a, -a}\[Transpose] ]
```

Now:

```
f2[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a,b,c}, {a,b,-c}, {a,-b,c}, {a,-b,-c}, {-a,b,c}, {-a,b,-c}, {-a,-b,c}, {-a,-b,-c}}
> ```

This is both shorter and an order of magnitude faster than rhermans's formulation:

```
First @ Timing @ Do[# @ Range @ 18, {100}] & /@ {f, f2}
```

> ```
> {4.368028, 0.358802}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another method:

```
plusMinus[symlist_List] := 
 With[{n = Length[symlist]}, 
  Map[symlist*# &, 
   Table[IntegerDigits[j, 2, n], {j, 2^n - 1}] /. 0 -> -1]]

plusMinus[{a, b, c, d}]

(*  Out[11]= {{-a, -b, -c, d}, {-a, -b, c, -d}, {-a, -b, c, d}, {-a, 
  b, -c, -d}, {-a, b, -c, d}, {-a, b, c, -d}, {-a, b, c, 
  d}, {a, -b, -c, -d}, {a, -b, -c, d}, {a, -b, c, -d}, {a, -b, c, 
  d}, {a, b, -c, -d}, {a, b, -c, d}, {a, b, c, -d}, {a, b, c, d}} *)
```

If you do not need to maintain ordering there is also this.

```
plusMinus2[symlist_List] := 
 Map[Join[-Complement[symlist, #], #] &, Subsets[symlist]]

plusMinus2[{a, b, c, d}]

(* Out[19]= {{-a, -b, -c, -d}, {-b, -c, -d, a}, {-a, -c, -d, 
  b}, {-a, -b, -d, c}, {-a, -b, -c, d}, {-c, -d, a, b}, {-b, -d, a, 
  c}, {-b, -c, a, d}, {-a, -d, b, c}, {-a, -c, b, d}, {-a, -b, c, 
  d}, {-d, a, b, c}, {-c, a, b, d}, {-b, a, c, d}, {-a, b, c, d}, {a, 
  b, c, d}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

For symbolic input data [`BooleanMinterms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanMinterms.html) and [`BooleanMaxterms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanMaxterms.html) may be of use:

```
g = Block[{And = List, Not = (-# &)}, Table[BooleanMinterms[{i-1}, {##}], {i, 2^Length[{##}]}]] &;

g[a, b, c, d]
(* {{-a,-b,-c,-d},{-a,-b,-c,d},{-a,-b,c,-d},{-a,-b,c,d},{-a,b,-c,-d},{-a,b,-c,d},
    {-a,b,c,-d},{-a,b,c,d},{a,-b,-c,-d},{a,-b,-c,d},{a,-b,c,-d},{a,-b,c,d},
    {a,b,-c,-d},{a,b,-c,d},{a,b,c,-d},{a,b,c,d}} *)
```

`BooelanMaxTerms` can be used similarly with `||` playing the role of `&&` above.